# Hard family for degree-$D$ MAX-3LIN

Tags: sat, approximation-hardness, linear-equations

Max 3LIN is the problem where one is given a linear system of  equations $C$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $3$ variables per equation, and needs to determine the maximum number of equations that can be satisfied. There cannot be two different equations involving the same $3$ variables. Degree-$D$ MAX-3LIN has the additional property that each variable appears in at most $D$ of the equations.

I would like to know whether there is a family of instances $C_i$ for degree-$D$ MAX-3LIN (with $i$ variables in instance $C_i$) where $\forall c > 0$, the fraction of all $2^i$ possible assignments that satisfy at least $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{D}}$ of the equations goes to $0$ as $i$ goes to infinity.

Note that:

- Under reasonable conjectures, if we replace the quantifier on $c$ to $\exists$ the statement is true, by a 2001 hardness of approximation [result](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=380839) from Trevisan.
- There also exist values of $c$ for which there will always be at least one assignment that satisfies $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{D}}$, following a 2015 [result](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/frontdoor.php?source_opus=5298) from Barak et al.